# Android: create an ImageButton for Speaker On/Off

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, imagebutton

I am writing an app, where in a game a score is counted and displayed.

Now I would like to give the opportunity to switch ON/Off the speakers. I think, to use an ImageButton should be the solution.

But how do I "dim" the button, when speaker is Off, but the button has to remain active. invisibility or disable is not the solution. Is ist best, to change the Image in the button?

Does anybody has an example for a switch On/Off button please.

I am working on AndroidStudio4.1 and Kotlin

Comment: Was the answer provided correct? Would you mark it of so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is better to have a checkbox, because that view handles true/false states by default. You have to create a drawable for the button and then set it as a button.

Let's say your drawable is `cb_selector_sound`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_sound_on" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_sound_off" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

and then use it in the button like this:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/soundCheckbox"
    android:button="@drawable/cb_selector_sound"
    .../>
```

So then you can listen the checkbox changing

```
//find the view
soundCheckbox.setOnCheckeChangedListener {_, isChecked ->
    if (isChecked) {
        //turn sound on
    } else {
       //turn sound off
    }

}
```

So the view worries about the appearance and you worried about the logic